# How to express these DTD statements?

Tags: xml, dtd

```
1. <!ELEMENT slide (title +, | topiclist)>
2. <!ELEMENT slide (title | topiclist) *>
```

We can say for `<!ELEMENT name (first, last)>` - the name element is the parent of exactly one fist and last elements, but I've no idea how to express above point 1 and 2. Can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Express them how? in English? in another formalism?  in ... what?

Answer (score 0):

In the content models of element declarations, you have characters that specify order:

`|` = choice ("or")

`,` = sequence ("followed by")

You also have characters that indicate occurrence:

`+` = one or more

`?` = zero or one

`*` = zero or more

If there is no indicator, that means the element must appear exactly once.

Also, parentheses are used for grouping.

Using the description above, let's see if we can answer your questions...

> 1. `<!ELEMENT slide (title+, | topiclist)>`

The `, |` is invalid. I'm assuming this is supposed to be just `,`. If not let me know.

This is saying the `slide` element must contain one or more (at least one) `title` element followed by exactly one `topiclist`.

> 2. `<!ELEMENT slide (title | topiclist) *>`

This is saying the `slide` element can contain zero or more `title` or `topiclist` elements (in any order).

Also, your example:

> `<!ELEMENT name (first, last)>`

would be better described as:

The `name` element must contain exactly one `first` element followed by exactly one `last` element. (You were missing the sequence in your description.)